# Detecting a repeated sequence with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a text example like

> `0s11 0s12 0s33 my name is 0sgfh 0s1 0s22 0s87`

I want to detect the consecutive sequences that start 0s.

So, the expected output should be `0s11 0s12 0s33`, `0sgfh 0s1 0s22 0s87`

I tried using regex

```
(0s\w+)
```

but that would detect each `0s11`, `0s12`, `0s33`,  etc. individually.

Any idea on how to modify the pattern?

Comment: Maybe group the group? https://regex101.com/r/wA4iXC/1

Comment: OP, you can check the top comment, Grouping should do the trick.

Comment: Guess you want to [use `{2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/wA4iXC/2) (*two or more*) instead of `+` (*one or more*) with the pattern from @user3783243

Answer (score 1):

To get those 2 matches where there are at least 2 consecutive  parts:

```
\b0s\w+(?:\s+0s\w+)+
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `0s\w+` Match `os` and 1+ word chars
- `(?:\s+0s\w+)+` Repeat 1 or more times whitespace chars followed by `0s` and 1+ word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lAJyzM/1)

If you also want to match a single occurrence:

```
\b0s\w+(?:\s+0s\w+)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q7LEx1/1)

**Note** that `\w+` matches 1 or more word characters so it would not match only `0s`

Answer (score 0):

Should be doable with `re.findall()`. Your pattern was correct! :)

```
import re
testString = "0s11 0s12 0s33 my name is 0sgfh 0s1 0s22 0s87"
print(re.findall('0s\w', testString))

['0s11', '0s12', '0s33', '0sgfh', '0s1', '0s22', '0s87']
```

Hope this helps!